# Can i Write to Embedded Resource Text File?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, c#-4.0

im stucking with Writing to Text File in the Resource, i can read from
the specified file, but cant write, its says Stream is not writeable.
there is any way to fix it ? i do it for my program builder, thanks in advice!

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: C# - i dont think its does matter

Comment: looks like there are four tag word choices there.  C++, Obj C, C & C-Sharp.

Comment: im new just tagged everything i saw :D , well there is an option?

Comment: OSX or iOS?  Ad an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not write the the application bundle, pick another location, perhaps the Documents directory on iOS or the Application Support directory in OSX.

On iOS the resource bundle is also signed, another reason writing to it is not allowed.